# .htaccess проблема

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

Решил добавить простейший чатик в реальном времени, который заносит данные в базу сообщение и тут же его выводит, для сайта в процедурном стиле на PHP.

В нём есть файл .htaccess  (его содержимое ниже). А сама проблема заключается в том, что из-за него почему-то не работает чатик. А точнее, полностью не работает скрипт, ничто не попадает в базу и из неё не выгружается. Если .htaccess удалить, то всё сразу работает прекрасно. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему ...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options All -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^resource/(.*)$ resource/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/(.*)$ catalog/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddType 'text/html; charset=utf-8' .html .htm .shtml
```

Файл с формой и скриптом:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(setInterval(function() {
     $("#messages").load('ajaxLoad.php');
  }, 500));



  $("#userArea").submit(function(){
    $.post('ajaxPost.php', $('#userArea').serialize(), function(data){
        $("#messages").append('<div>'+data+'</div>');
        
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div id="messages"></div>
    <form action="" id="userArea" style="margin: 0 auto; font-size: 23px; text-align: center;">
      <h1>Чат:</h1>
      <input type="text" value="" name="messages" />
      <input type="submit"  value="ответить !" />
    </form>    
</div>
```

И три маленький файла, конфиг для подключения к базе:

```
<?php       
    $config = array();
    $config['host'] = 'тут';
    $config['user'] = 'всё';
    $config['pass'] = 'заполнено';
    $config['table'] = 'правильно';

    include('mysqli.class.php');

    $db = new DB($config);
 ?>
```

Файл который загружает в базу:

```
<?php 
    include('config.php');
    $db->query('SELECT * FROM messages');
    $data = $db->Get();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        echo '<div>' .$value['message1'].'</div>'  ;
    }
?>
```

И который выгружает:

```
<?php 
   include('config.php');

   $message = $_POST['messages'];

   $db->Query("INSERT INTO messages(message1) VALUES ('$message')");

   echo $message;

?>
```

Comment: И ещё уточню, что в файле подключения к бд есть строка include("mysqli.class.php");. Это файл с классом BD, который отлавливает ошибки и подключает к нужное базе.

Comment: Заметил что проблема в файле .htaccess, так как если его удалить, то всё работает. Но удалить этот файл - не выход ...

Comment: в общем , я знаю что это надо по любому но если у меня на сервере в htaccess есть эта строка то у меня тоже весь сайт не работает , уберите и проверьте Options All -Indexes

Comment: Это не помогло. Но я убрал строки:
RewriteRule ^.*$ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

и скрипт с чатиком заработал, НО без этих строк не работает система "красивых ссылок". Чем можно заменить или как отредактировать эти строки, чтобы всё заработало ?

Comment: я в htaacess не спец, делал всё наугад , простите - я по этому ни сделал ответом , что не был уверен в этом , но у меня это сработало

Answer (score 1):

Протестил у себя, работает вот этот вариант, без **RewriteBase /**

[Что такое RewriteBase и когда его лучше использовать](http://www.shtogrin.com/library/web/mod_rewrite/doc/RewriteBase/)

```
RewriteEngine on
Options All -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^resource/(.*)$ resource/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/(.*)$ catalog/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddType 'text/html; charset=utf-8' .html .htm .shtml
```

Comment: Да, всё работает. Вот только теперь чтобы попасть на www.website.com/example нужно написать 
www.website.com/page/example.php - что приравнивается к удалению файла .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Смею предположить, что данный .htaccess файл писали не Вы. Раз без него у Вас всё работает, предлагаю тогда его упростить.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло ...
нужно заменить каким-то образом эти две строчки
RewriteRule ^.*$ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
или дописать что-то к ним. ибо если их удалить, то всё работает ...

Comment: RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

Comment: Что простите ? Не понял.

Comment: Сорри, случано отправил.

Попробуйте заменить строку: RewriteRule ^.*$ [NC,L]
На строку RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

Comment: К сожалению это тоже не помогло ...